# Jump between open windows on multiple monitors in Task View on Windows 10 with keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, multiple-monitors, task-view

I'm using two monitors with Windows 10 and I have a few windows open on each monitor. When I open the Task View (`Win` + `Tab`) I can only navigate between the main monitor's windows with keyboard (using arrow keys or the `Tab` key). I see the other display's windows on that display but can't figure out how to cycle through those windows with my keyboard.

Is there a way I can give focus to secondary monitor's windows in the Task View using keyboard?

To put it another way, how do I select the first item on the right monitor in the following screenshot using keyboard?

[Screenshot of Task-View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeGf6.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a multi-step process.

1. WIN+TAB to open task view.
2. Press SHIFT+TAB to move focus up to the Desktop selector (it reads "+ New desktop").
3. Press SHIFT+Tab again to switch focus to the next display.
4. Use TAB and the arrow keys to select the app you want.

You can accomplish the same thing with tab and the arrow keys alone, but SHIFT+TAB is the quick way to get focus on the next display.

Comment: This only works if Timeline feature is disabled. Otherwise step 3 will select the search icon instead of switching displays.

Comment: I wouldn't use a MS account for the world, so I can't test that, but pressing TAB & SHIFT+TAB combinations cycles through the focuses for me (including but not limited to the search icon). I'll try to find a client device that's using a MS account to test it.

Comment: I don't know if you have misunderstood the question or this combination of keys no longer works, but what you are describing switches between (virtual) *Desktops*, not monitors. I still can't find a way to go with the keyboard to the windows on the right *monitor*, as asked in the OP.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: 3 Monitor solution:

Expanding on the comment by @thesdev:
In case you have 3 monitors like me, this is what you need to do:

First you need to disable the Timeline feature in Task View for this to work:
https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+Task+View+disable+timeline

After that the following key sequences work after you have Task View displayed with Win+Tab (assuming you have a 3 monitor setup with the main monitor being in the middle):

|⬅ Switch focus to the monitor on the Left:
Press Shift+Tab 3 times

➡| Switch focus to the monitor on the right:
Press Tab 4 times

Answer (score 0):

**3 Monitor solution**: (Expanding on the comment by @shawn @thesdev)

In case you have 3 monitors like me, this is what you need to do:

First you need to **disable the Timeline feature** in Task View for this to work:

https://google.com/search?q=windows+Task+View+disable+timeline

After that the following key sequences work right after you have Task View displayed with Win+Tab (assuming you have a 3 monitor setup with the main monitor being in the middle):

- ⬅ Switch focus to the monitor on the **Left**: Press **Shift+Tab 3 times**
- ➡ Switch focus to the monitor on the **right**: Press **Tab 4 times**

You might want to write an **Autohotkey script** to this. Such as:

```
#IfWinActive, Task View ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow
F1:: Send +{Tab 3}  ;Switch to monitor on the Left
F3:: Send  {Tab 4}  ;Switch to monitor on the Right
```

More on #IfWinActive and Autohotkey can be found here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_IfWinActive.htm

Answer (score -2):

Try using Win+Ctrl and arrow key to jump to the next windows

Comment: Win+CTRL does not cycle between open windows. It resizes the active window.

Comment: You’re talking about alt+win +arrow key

Comment: No, I'm not, but I was not completely correct either. Win+up/down arrow resizes the active window. Win+CTRL+up/down arrow is not bound and so the CTRL is ignored and it resizes the active window. Win+CTRL+right/left arrow switches between active Virtual Desktops, which is NOT the same thing as switching between applications as OP asked. Unless you are running a custom set of keybindings, Win+CTRL+(any) arrow does NOT switch between different running applications. See here for proof: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec

Comment: "Try using Win+Ctrl and arrow key to jump to the next windows" - Doesn't work;