# How to navigate to second monitor in Win+Tab menu?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, keyboard-navigation

When you press <kbd>Windows + Tab</kbd> you get an overlay over all monitors that looks like this:
[image: 1]

In this menu, you can see different "tiles" on the different monitors. Each is an application that is open on that monitor.

You can navigate this menu using your keyboard by using the <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to focus that application. This is all great!

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to select apps on monitors other than the main one (middle). You can see a tile on the main/middle monitor has a white outline to indicate it is selected. I can move the selection to different apps on the same monitor, but I can't get the selection to go to other monitors.

Is there a keyboard shortcut one can use to navigate to apps on different monitors?

Comment: Here is an workaround shared but with some shortages: use Shift Tab to switch desktops (disable timeline feature)
https://superuser.com/questions/1386932/jump-between-open-windows-on-multiple-monitors-in-task-view-on-windows-10-with-k

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this feature was called "Task View" so I didn't find that thread while searching